# In java, how to read a fixed length from the inputstream and save as a file?

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

In java, how to read a fixed length from the inputstream and save as a file?
eg. I want to read 5M from inputStream, and save as downloadFile.txt or whatever.(BUFFERSIZE=1024)

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(downloadFile);
byte buffer [] = new byte[BUFFERSIZE];
int temp = 0;
while ((temp = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1)
{
    fos.write(buffer, 0, temp);
}
```

Comment: Keep reading and writing until you get 5M--you know how many bytes are read; use math.

Comment: inputStream.read(buffer,0,1024); will do that.

read upto a count so u get 5MB:)

Comment: @Krishnanunni Actually, don't even need that--`read(byte[] buf)` will attempt to read `buf.length` bytes.

Comment: @DaveNewton: But what if you've only got 10 bytes left to read? You may not want to read any more from the input stream, and it's a pain to have to create an extra buffer just for that.

Comment: @JonSkeet [It *attempts* to read `buf.length` bytes, and returns the number actually read.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read(byte[])) It calls read(buf, off, len), which calls read(); they all stop reading at EOF.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Yes - which is why in my code I use the return value. My point is that if there's more data in the input stream but we don't want to read beyond the part we're copying, you don't *want* to fill the buffer necessarily. Suppose this is actually a network stream, and we know that the first 5M needs to be saved to one file, and the next 5M to another.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, I see what you're saying. Yep, if you're reading something where going past the 5M limit is bad, you'd definitely need to specify the length.

Comment: @DaveNewton: And even if you didn't mind over-reading, you'd still need something to make sure you didn't accidentally write more than you wanted - e.g. your final read got 1024 bytes when you only want to write 10. If you're going to want a `Math.min` call, you might as well do it on the reading side and the writing side drops out :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options:

1. Just keep reading and writing until you either reach the end of the input or you've copied enough:

   ```
   byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
   int bytesLeft = 5 * 1024 * 1024; // Or whatever
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(input);
   try {
     FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(output);
     try {
       while (bytesLeft > 0) {
         int read = fis.read(buffer, 0, Math.min(bytesLeft, buffer.length);
         if (read == -1) {
           throw new EOFException("Unexpected end of data");
         }
         fos.write(buffer, 0, read);
         bytesLeft -= read;
       }
     } finally {
       fos.close(); // Or use Guava's Closeables.closeQuietly,
                    // or try-with-resources in Java 7
     }
   } finally {
     fis.close(); 
   }
   ```
2. Read all 5M into memory in one call, e.g. using `DataInputStream.readFully`, and then write it out in one go. Simpler, but obviously uses more memory.

Comment: It works great for what it was requested. However, I have a slightly different scenario. I have a large log file that I need to split into 5MB files.

Comment: @J.Tribbiani: Then I suggest you ask a different question, with more details.